# make lookup option only available if status not completed

Tags: 2010, lookup-column

I'm creating a way to tag documents against projects, so I've created a list for the projects and numerous libraries that access the list as a lookup for tagging purpose.

The list also has a status column also. When I create items in the list, the library can pick the values from the list as normal. However I don't want lookup available to tag documents if the item from the list has it status value set to completed.

I thought of creating an intermediate list that adds and removes items depending on status and then using this for the library, but sounds messy. I have 4 libraries that need to act in this way from the same list. 
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Hide the column on the EditForm with some javascript

Comment: Hi Its not the column I want to hide, I need to hide a lookup value if its status is Completed.

Comment: Then you need javascript  to delete options from the select dropdown: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/select/option/